# ARKit plane visualization

Tags: arkit

I want to be able to visualize the planes that my ARKit app detects. How do I do that?

[This is what I want to be able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg7kF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new AR project in Xcode with SceneKit and Obj-C, then add these to ViewController.m:

```
//as a class or global variable:
NSMapTable *planes;

//add to viewWillAppear:
configuration.planeDetection = ARPlaneDetectionHorizontal;

//to viewDidLoad:
planes = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory
                               valueOptions:NSMapTableWeakMemory];

//new functions: 
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor {
if( [anchor isKindOfClass:[ARPlaneAnchor class]] ){
    [planes setObject:anchor forKey:node];
    ARPlaneAnchor *pa = anchor;

    SCNNode *pn = [SCNNode node];
    [node addChildNode:pn];
    pn.geometry = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:pa.extent.x height:pa.extent.z];
    SCNMaterial *m = [SCNMaterial material];
    m.emission.contents = UIColor.blueColor;
    m.transparency = 0.1;
    pn.geometry.materials = @[m];
    pn.position = SCNVector3Make(pa.center.x, -0.002, pa.center.z);
    pn.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-M_PI / 2.0, 1, 0, 0);
  }
}

- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didUpdateNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor {
if( [anchor isKindOfClass:[ARPlaneAnchor class]] ){
    [planes setObject:anchor forKey:node];

    ARPlaneAnchor *pa = anchor;
    SCNNode *pn = [node childNodes][0];
    SCNPlane *pg = pn.geometry;
    pg.width = pa.extent.x;
    pg.height = pa.extent.z;
    pn.position = SCNVector3Make(pa.center.x, -0.002, pa.center.z);
  }
}

- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didRemoveNode:(nonnull SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(nonnull ARAnchor *)anchor{
[planes removeObjectForKey:node];
}
```

You'll see translucent planes, give `m.emission.contents` a texture if you feel so.

Alternatively get the [Example App from Apple in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip)